# What is "->" after function declaration?

Tags: c++, c++11

In one system header file, I see the expression like this:

```
auto create_task(_Ty _Param) -> task<typename details::_TaskTypeFromParam<_Ty>::_Type>
{…}
```

I don't know what "->" means, it isn't  pointer expression or lambda expression, can anyone help me?

Comment: By the way, for Googling, the term is "Trailing return type".

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It's the new function declaration syntax from C++11, and it's called the "trailing return type". At the end of a function declaration, `->` means that the following is the return type of the function. It can only be used when the `auto` keyword is used instead of an actual return type where you would normally expect it.

For instance, these two declarations are compatible:

```
int foo();
auto foo() -> int;
```

Depending on your tastes, you may find it prettier than the old declaration syntax, especially when the return type is extremely long/complex:

```
task<typename details::_TaskTypeFromParam<_Ty>::_Type> create_task(_Ty _Param);
auto create_task(_Ty _Param) -> task<typename details::_TaskTypeFromParam<_Ty>::_Type>;
```

But sometimes it can be necessary with templates, when the return type of the function could vary with the arguments.

Say you want a templated function to add variables:

```
template<typename T>
T add(const T& x, const T& y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

That's great, but you'll only be able to add variables of the same type. Suppose you would like to be able to add variables of any type (like `add((int)1, (double)2)`).

```
template<typename T, typename U>
??? add(const T& x, const U& y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

---

**EDIT**: note that in C++14 and onwards, it's legal to write `auto add(const T& x, const U& y)`, without a trailing return type, for function **definitions** (in other words, when you define the body of your function).

---

The problem is that you can't tell in advance what the result type of `x + y` will be. As templates stand, they could even be non-integral types. (Wouldn't you like to be able to do `add(std::string("x"), "y")`?)

`Decltype`, along with the new function declaration syntax, lets you solve this problem.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto add(const T& x, const U& y) -> decltype(x + y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

`Decltype` "returns" the type of an expression. Since you need `x` and `y` to have been declared for `decltype(x + y)` to work, you need the new syntax.

Comment: You have access to the argument types even with a regular return type, since the template parameters are always declared first. What you don't have access to is the parameter names, or even the function name.

Comment: Why couldnt have `decltype(x + y) add(const T& x, const U& y)` worked?