# Use of -> in function declaration

Tags: c++, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is “->” after function declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417197/what-is-after-function-declaration)

I've just come across the following examples of C++ functions using the new `auto` keyword, and I was hoping someone could help me understand what the syntax means.

```
template <class T, class U>
auto add(T t, U u) -> decltype(t + u);

auto f = [](int a, int b) -> int {
   return a*b;
};
```

Specifically, I'm confused about the user of `->` in the function signature and I would expect these to be written in the as

```
template <class T, class U>
auto add(T t, U u)
{
    decltype(t + u);
}

auto f = [](int a, int b){
    return a*b;
};
```

What's the `->` operator doing in there, and where can I learn more about this syntax?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What's the `->` operator doing in there?

That's a *trailing return type*. Instead of:

```
int f();
```

you can equivalently write:

```
auto f() -> int;
```

If the return type depends on the function parameter types, then you need to use this form; the parameters aren't available until after they've been declared:

```
decltype(t+u) add(T t, U u); // Error: uses `t` and `u` before they're declared
auto add(T t, U u) -> decltype(t + u); // OK
```

Also, if you want to specify the return type of a lambda, then you must use this form; although, as you point out, in many cases (including this one) you don't need to specify that at all.

Answer (score 3):

[dcl.spec.auto]/2 explains how to write function declaration with auto return type :

> The auto type-specifier may appear with a function declarator with a trailing-return-type (8.3.5) in any context where such a declarator is valid.

And then later, in [dcl.fct]/12, there is a note :

Typedefs and trailing-return-types are sometimes convenient when the return type of a function is complex. For example, the function fpif above could have been declared

```
typedef int IFUNC(int);
IFUNC* fpif(int);
```

or

```
auto fpif(int)->int(*)(int)
```

A trailing-return-type is most useful for a type that would be more complicated to specify before the declarator-id:

```
template <class T, class U> auto add(T t, U u) -> decltype(t + u);
```

rather than

```
template <class T, class U> decltype((*(T*)0) + (*(U*)0)) add(T t, U u);
```

Answer (score 2):

This syntax (so called *trailing-return-type*) is a workaround for using expression as return type, as the following:

```
template <class T, class U>
   decltype(t + u) add(T t, U u) { ... }
```

... would not be correct in C++.

Have to say this issue is explained well enough (I suppose) in [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Alternative_function_syntax).

Comment: ... it is not correct because it uses `t` and `u` before they are in scope (they're only declared in the parameter list).

Answer (score 1):

`->` is a *trailing return type*.

C++11 proposed an alternative function declaration syntax. 
`auto` keyword takes a place of the usual function return type, and the actual return type goes after `->`.

For example,

```
auto f (int a, int b) -> int;
```

is equivalent to

```
int f(int a, int b);
```

This feature is most useful for template functions where the return type has to be deduced from the template parameters.

For example,

```
template <class T, class U>
auto add(T t, U u) -> decltype(t + u);
```

the return type would be the type of the expression `(t+u)`.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the -> operator doing in there, and where can I learn more 
>   about this syntax?

There's a very nice explaination about this on [cprogramming](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-auto-decltype-return-value-after-function.html).

The essence of using -> (in your case) or auto, decltype is convenience and letting you focus more on the programming logic.

The *trailing return type* (->) helps you include the return type information in the function declaration itself.

In case of your alternate example:

```
auto add(T t, U u)
{
    decltype(t + u);
}
```

If the function is fairly complex, then it would be pretty difficult (not obviously obvious) for a reader of your program to figure out what the expected return type is.

Answer (score 0):

The -> operator in function declarations specifies the return type for functions returning "auto". It's defined in chapter 8 of the C++11 standard.